# Weird output running a fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, fibonacci

Brand new to using python, need help figuring out why my command line is spitting out huge strings of numbers and not the fib sequence up to the var I pass in. Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print a
        a, b = b, a+b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fib(sys.argv[1])
```

Now before I did sys.argv[1] or [1:] I was able to put in a sequence in n up to the number I wanted. I.e if I entered n as 12 I would get 0,1,1,3,5,8 which is correct. However I cannot get this to work. I did a print statement after the def fib(n): as print n. It would return my sys.argv pass in.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget to convert the input argument (a string) into an integer type:

```
fib(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you that did work, I will close the question come min 8. If I might bother you enough, why would I need to specify that it is an integer and not have python assume that on its own if I pass in the value? Is it seeing the name of the program then the string I pass in?

Comment: @camihan In all programming languages that have some mechanism for receiving command-line arguments, they're passed as `string` types. Reflect on it, Python doesn't have a way to know what data type is being passed as parameter (is it a `"1"`, a `1` or a `1.0`?), so it assumes they're all strings and it's the programmer's task to convert them to the appropriate data type.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fib(int(sys.argv[1]))`, that might be the problem, but I didn't try it.